# Immediate Restart After Power On - Before BIOS

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, power, reboot

When I originally built this PC, it had an issue with randomly restarting.  I proceeded to try a bunch of things and ended up unplugging everything except the power switch and the cards I have in it.  Everything worked until now, when I decided to move it from one apartment to another.  Below is a list of what I've tried.  I still think it's shorting out but I am not sure what is causing it.  I'm trying to avoid removing the mother board or re-seating the processor without trying everything else.  It does not get to the BIOS / POST.

- Tested power supply using paper clip, worked fine.
- Removed all plugged in components from the back panel except power
- Ensured my stand offs are tightened, I have 2 in plug the main one sitting through the middle of the mother board.  I've read the screws being over sized could cause this but the ones I have in aren't excessive (They're not tiny, I'd consider them pretty normal).  Has anyone experienced this?
- Removing the power switch after turning it on.

Ideas?

Comment: 1) Do you have the system on a UPS? (momentary power winks will do this.)  2)A bad power supply can behave like this (momentary power drop that your paper clip test wouldn't show or something faking or misinterpreting a shutdown signal).  3)A heat problem.  Blow off the fans, vents, and heat sinks with a can of compressed air.  4) it's probably not your screws.  If you think there's any possibility, though, put insulating washers between the screw head and the motherboard except for any screw intended to provide a chassis ground (though may not be necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being my processor.  I ended up RMAing the motherboard then the processor.  Same problem with multiple motherboards.  I have no good way to determine it was the processor other than it fixed the issue.  If someone else can explain why this can happen I'd gladly select it as the correct answer.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these

1. Remove the RAM
2. Rub the golden platings at bottom of RAM with eraser
3. Clean the RAM slots with a dry brush
4. Insert RAM again

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried reseating it, what is the purpose of the dry brush? I blew it out with compressed air to see if there was anything in there.

Comment: Oh...then no need for a dry brush. However, let me know the eraser trick. Its much used here.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already re-seated all plugs, cards, and memory and still can't get it running...

Unplug the AC power, hold in the power button for 10 seconds, sometimes this works to bleed down the capacitors in the power circuit.  Then plug in AC power and try it out.  Even if it does work, I'd replace that Power Supply Unit, it's most likely the culprit.